# Zapier Python zap that I want to check if a field endswith .mov

Tags: python, zapier

I am trying to test a Zapier field with python code block to see if it ends with .mov.  If so, I want to remove the .mov.  If not, just return the field as is.  The code I have works, but I have added a .lower() to make it work and don't understand why it behaves that way.

I have tried multiple variations but the only one that seems to work is adding string formatting .lower() in the variable.

```
formatted_str = input_data['text']
if formatted_str.endswith('.mov'):
    formatted_str = formatted_str[:-4]
return {'formatted_str':formatted_str.lower()}
```

I would like to return the results without having to change it to all lower case.  I know it is possible, but I am not having any luck.  Thank you so much!

Comment: what happens when you don't include `.lower`? Is there an error?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Sorry, the answer needed to be edited.  It is:  ```formatted_str = input_data['text']
if formatted_str.endswith('.mov'):
    formatted_str = formatted_str[:-4]
return {'text':formatted_str}```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Zapier folks, I figured out my issue.  Thank you!

```
formatted_str = input_data['text']
if formatted_str.endswith('.mov'):
    formatted_str = formatted_str[:-4]
return {'text':formatted_str}
```